# Moving Vagrant machines off of old computer

Tags: vagrant

Here are the steps that I went to move off of old computer

```
Copied ~/.vagrant to USB drive
Copied ~/Virtual Box/* to USB hard drive
Copied clients to USB hard drive
```

Each subdirectory in clients looks like this:

[image]

HERE IS MY PROBLEM :

[image]

[image]

And here is my Vagrant file where I set the name:

[image]

My problem is that it wont bring up the Vagrant machine that I copied over, CAN SOMEONE PLEASE TELL ME WHY VAGRANT ISN'T RECOGNIZING THE MACHINE AND STARTING IT. Why does it want to create a new box if I told it what box to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the VM is not much important - what is really important is the **uuid** of the machine.

When you moved the VirtualBox VMs to your USD, when you had reopened VirtualBox those VM became inaccessible so you had to reimport them and thus it recreated a new uuid for the VM and vagrant which keeps track of the uuid was not able to retrieve it from VirtualBox then it recreated a new VM.

VirtualBox keeps the link between the uuid of your VM and the physical location in the file `./Library/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml` if you open this file, you will find the entry:

```
<MachineRegistry>
  <MachineEntry uuid="{cf5c9fe6-be04-40f8-aeec-415bb0b74e37}" src="/Users/fhenri/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/tacsvn_default_1386768343/tacsvn_default_1386768343.vbox"/>
  <MachineEntry uuid="{08732b8b-e80e-4707-9f4c-842bdcdb2442}" src="/Users/fhenri/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/pwslocal_default_1386328036/pwslocal_default_1386328036.vbox"/>
  <MachineEntry uuid="{ced87630-c5d9-4396-9fc1-7a9277ec2f4a}" src="/Volumes/Passport/vm/AribaSandbox_sourcing_1386791950/AribaSandbox_sourcing_1386791950.vbox"/>
  <MachineEntry uuid="{b9fc4466-2382-4629-9fcf-f414ab5093fd}" src="/Volumes/Passport/vm/AribaSandbox_asm_1386792168/AribaSandbox_asm_1386792168.vbox"/>
  <MachineEntry uuid="{4442b12f-2b52-4edd-aa94-e87e2f4e54cd}" src="/Volumes/Passport/vm/fhsolution.com/fhsolution.com.vbox"/>
  <MachineEntry uuid="{650472d0-3bb7-4a64-9035-8a6c6e012eb3}" src="/Users/fhenri/.docker/machine/machines/default/default/default.vbox"/>
  <MachineEntry uuid="{17140ebf-94f3-4434-8576-e8c19cce05f4}" src="/Users/fhenri/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/ubuntu_web_1452632837414_99758/ubuntu_web_1452632837414_99758.vbox"/>
  <MachineEntry uuid="{4bbf157f-00d4-4ee6-8aa1-fc3b170ad1a9}" src="/Users/fhenri/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/ubuntu_default_1457125361118_11876/ubuntu_default_1457125361118_11876.vbox"/>
  <MachineEntry uuid="{ff197c01-2f63-4e46-b8b6-98757a6f5084}" src="/Users/fhenri/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/java_default_1460033990347_57680/java_default_1460033990347_57680.vbox"/>
  <MachineEntry uuid="{c4a3a84c-6cf3-4d8f-87de-47b6abe41b5d}" src="/Users/fhenri/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/ubuntu_default_1461321611815_8129/ubuntu_default_1461321611815_8129.vbox"/>
  <MachineEntry uuid="{57559b51-0446-4b62-98c6-100bd09700a0}" src="/Users/fhenri/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/debian_default_1461336132946_97987/debian_default_1461336132946_97987.vbox"/>
</MachineRegistry>
```

Vagrant is keeping those uuid in an `id` file inside the `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox` of your project folder so both must match and point to the right folder within your USB drive

Comment: Frederic, I was close. I was reading and saw the hard disks had UUID's and thats what I thought I needed to change, but you added clarity. I am going to mark this as correct without having my computer